# How to change select based on another select in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, drop-down-menu, vuetify.js

I have methods in a Web Api that loads the first select and loads the second select, but the second  has a parameter that pass it from the first select.

The url for the second  looks like this: http://localhost:58209/api/Tecnico/Tanque/?estacionid=@parameter

Ok. I use Vuetify in front end, and to try load the second v-select, i use this:

```
<v-flex xs12 sm8 md6>
   <v-select autocomplete :items="itemsEstacion" item-text="numeroEstacion" item-value="estacionID" prepend-icon="local_gas_station" :loading="loading" label="Seleccionar Destino" v-model="selectEstacion"></v-select>
</v-flex>

   <v-flex xs12 sm8 md6>
     <v-select autocomplete :items="itemsTanque" v-model="selectTanque" item-text="NumTanque" item-value="ID" v-on:change="cargarTanques(itemsEstacion.estacionID)" prepend-icon="opacity" label="Seleccionar Tanque"></v-select>
   </v-flex>
```

In `data() return{}` i have:

```
  selectEstacion: "",
  selectTanque: null,
  itemsEstacion: [],
  itemsTanque: [],
```

These are my methods:
- For the first select

```
    cargarEstaciones() {
  this.loading = true;
  axios
    .get("GetEstaciones", {
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token")
      }
    })
    .then(response => {
      this.loading = false;
      console.log(response);
      this.itemsEstacion = response.data;
      //this.snackbar = true;
      //this.textSnackbar = "Se han cargado correctamente las estaciones";
    })
    .catch(error => {
      this.loading = false;
      if (error.response.status != null) {
        switch (error.response.status) {
          case 204:
            this.snackbar = true;
            this.textSnackbar = error.response.data;
            break;
        }
      }
    });
},
```

-For the second select:

```
    cargarTanques(estacionID) {
  axios
    .get("Tecnico/Tanque/?estacionID=" + estacionID, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token")
      }
    })
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      this.itemsTanque = response.data;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      if (error.response.status != null) {
        switch (error.response.status) {
          case 404:
            this.snackbar = true;
            this.textSnackbar = error.response.data;
            break;
          case 500:
            this.snackbar = true;
            this.textSnackbar = error.response.data;
        }
      }
    });
},
```

And to handle the event i put this on `watch:{}`

```
    selectEstacion: function() {
  this.cargarTanques(this.itemsEstacion.estacionID);
}
```

But the parameter is undefined, always. 
And the v-on:change it's not working, so i use watch() instead.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`itemsEstacion` is an array, that's why `itemsEstacion.estacionID` is alway undefined.

I've changed your code, move `v-on:change="cargarTanques"` to first select.

```
<v-flex xs12 sm8 md6>
    <v-select 
        autocomplete 
        :items="itemsEstacion" 
        item-text="numeroEstacion" 
        item-value="estacionID" 
        prepend-icon="local_gas_station" 
        :loading="loading" 
        label="Seleccionar Destino" 
        v-on:change="cargarTanques"
        v-model="selectEstacion">
    </v-select>
</v-flex>

<v-flex xs12 sm8 md6>
    <v-select 
        autocomplete 
        :items="itemsTanque" 
        v-model="selectTanque" 
        item-text="NumTanque" 
        item-value="ID" 
        prepend-icon="opacity" 
        label="Seleccionar Tanque">
    </v-select>
</v-flex>

cargarTanques() {
  axios
    .get("Tecnico/Tanque/?estacionID=" + this.itemsEstacion.estacionID, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token")
      }
    })
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      this.itemsTanque = response.data;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      if (error.response.status != null) {
        switch (error.response.status) {
          case 404:
            this.snackbar = true;
            this.textSnackbar = error.response.data;
            break;
          case 500:
            this.snackbar = true;
            this.textSnackbar = error.response.data;
        }
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: my select looks like this: `<v-select autocomplete :items="itemsEstacion" item-text="numeroEstacion" item-value="estacionID" prepend-icon="local_gas_station" :loading="loading" label="Seleccionar Destino" v-model="selectEstacion"></v-select>` the v-on:change doesn't work because when i select a value the first never catch it, after when i select new value. So i used a Watch instead, an looks like this: `    selectEstacion: function() {
      this.cargarTanques(this.selectEstacion.id);
    }` now the problem is the second select. Because not changed his value after i select new value

Comment: ... from the first select